# Sharepoint Designer 2013 -- Unable to see site pages

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer

I have admin/owner rights to this site and I have created over 200 aspx pages using the web browser interface.  I am able to connect to my site using Sharepoint Designer 2013, but when I click the site pages folder, no files show in the list. There are no filters set.

A colleague CAN see the files in her Sharepoint Designer and we have gone over permissions on the Sharepoint site (they are the same) and tried to find in SPDesigner what might be different, but could see no difference.

Please help.  Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried `All Files` --> `Site Pages`?